# Which is better, "a guide to travel procedures" or "a guide on travel procedures"?

Tags: grammar

My boss says it is better to use "A guide on travel procedures" as she is refering to procedures. Does that make sense?

Comment: I saw the graphics you posted on the older question. I'm afraid that they look a bit odd.  "A guide to"  would have been much better in all three cases.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on "a guide to..." Using "on' is rather odd. @BoldBen 
Thank you for your comment.